# Unusual closed form for an indefinite integral

Tags: indefinite-integrals

I was bored and started punching in some rational functions into WolframAlpha to integrate and I came across a closed form that I've never seen before and have no clue how it would even be derived.

The integral I took was $$
\int{\frac{dx}{Ax^3 + Bx^2 + Cx + D}}
$$
and the return value given was
$$
\sum_{\{\omega\ : \ A\omega^3 + B\omega^2 + C\omega + D = 0\}}{\frac{\ln{|-\omega + x|}}{3A\omega^2 + 2B\omega + C}} \color{silver}{+ \text{constant}}
$$
It seems as though in general,
$$
\int{\frac{dx}{\sum_{k=1}^n{A_kx^{n-k}}}} = \sum_{\{\omega\ : \ \sum_{k=1}^n{A_k\omega^{n-k}}=0\}}{\frac{\ln{|-\omega + x|}}{\frac{d}{dx}{\left(\sum_{k=1}^n{A_k\omega^{n-k}}\right)}}} \color{silver}{+ \text{constant}}
$$
Where does this come from? Is there a name for this type of indefinite integral?

Comment: $\int \dfrac{f'(x)}{f(x)}dx =  \ln | f(x) | + c$

Comment: @user172209 Unless I'm missing something I don't really see how that is relevant, could you explain please?

Comment: $\int \sum_i \dfrac{f_i'(x)}{f_i(x)}dx =  \sum_i \ln | f_i(x) | + c$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Partial fractions: if $P(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ with $n$ distinct roots
$\omega_1, \ldots, \omega_n$, then 
$$ \dfrac{1}{P(x)} = \sum_{j=1}^n \dfrac{c_j}{x - \omega_j}$$
where $c_j$ is the residue of $1/P(x)$ at $x=\omega_j$, which is $1/P'(\omega_j)$.
Then integrate.

Comment: Oh gosh, residues, I have absolutely no knowledge of complex analysis. The time will come when I can fully appreciate this answer, but for now thank you for elaborating!

Comment: @user3002473 You don't need complex analysis. All you need to know is to do partial fractions. (Yes, one way is to use residues, but there are other methods.)

Comment: Once you know $$ \dfrac{1}{P(x)} = \sum_{j=1}^n \dfrac{c_j}{x-\omega_j}$$ just multiply both sides by $x - \omega_j$ and take the limit as $x \to \omega_j$, using l'Hospital's rule on the left.