# How to compute $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\exp\left(-\frac{(x^2-13x-1)^2}{611x^2}\right)\ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, closed-form

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\exp\left(-\frac{(x^2-13x-1)^2}{611x^2}\right)\ dx$$

WolframAlpha gives a numerical answer of $43.8122$, which appears to be $\sqrt{611\pi}$. And playing with that, it seems that replacing $611$ with $a$ just gives $\sqrt{a\pi}$. My trouble is that the stuff in the exponential always seems to be just a big mess, and I haven't been able to get it into a form I can understand or deal with.

I would greatly appreciate seeing a method for solving this integral.

Comment: I have a strong feeling that you can use Feynman's trick on this, but I am still trying to find the correct one.

Comment: How can you be sure that $\sqrt{a\pi}$ is not just a good approximation ? Could you produce some values with more digits ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I'm not entirely sure if it's exactly $\sqrt{a\pi}$, but for every value of $a$ I've tried, WolframAlpha always gives a number very close to $\sqrt{a\pi}$. I was hoping this fact might help with solving the integral.

Comment: Working with very high precision, I can confirm that the result is exactly $\sqrt{a\pi}$ what you would get with $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{a}\right)\ dx=\sqrt{a\pi}$$

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Let $\displaystyle\;u(x) = \frac{x^2-13x-1}{x}\;$. As $x$ varies over $\mathbb{R}$, we have

- u(x) increases monotonically from $-\infty$ at $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ at $0^{-}$.
- u(x) increases monotonically from $-\infty$ at $0^{+}$ to $+\infty$ at $+\infty$.

This means as $x$ varies, $u(x)$ covered $(-\infty,\infty)$ twice.

Let $x_1(u) < 0$ and $x_2(u) > 0$ be the two roots of the equation for a given $u$:

$$u = u(x) = \frac{x^2-13x-1}{x} \quad\iff\quad x^2 - (13+u)x - 1 = 0$$
we have
$$x_1(u) + x_2(u) = 13 + u
\quad\implies\quad
\frac{dx_1}{du} + \frac{dx_2}{du} = 1.
$$
From this, we find

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-u(x)^2/611} dx
&= \left( \int_{-\infty}^{0^{-}} + \int_{0^{+}}^{+\infty}\right) e^{-u(x)^2/611} dx\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-u^2/611}\left(\frac{dx_1}{du} + \frac{dx_2}{du}\right) du\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-u^2/611} du\\
&= \sqrt{611\pi}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: This is a new technique for me (+1), I think it can be generalised. If so, what is the condition? Say $u(x)=\dfrac{px^2+qx+r}{sx}$

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova algebraically, $pr < 0$. Geometrically, this ensure the monotonicity of the $u(x)$ and $u$ cover $(-\infty,\infty)$ twice.

Comment: +1 for its potent to be generalized (to a higher degree, maybe?).

Comment: @sos440 the generalization is essentially the "Added" part of orangeskid answer.

Answer (score 23):

HINT:

For $a$ fixed

$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\exp\left(-\frac{(x^2+sx-b)^2}{a x^2}\right)\ dx$

is constant in $s$ and $b\ge 0$.

$\bf{Added:}$

The function $\frac{x^2 + s x - b}{x} = x - \frac{b}{x} + s$ invariates the Lebesgue measure as @achille hui: showed in his answer.

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$  $\alpha_1$, $\ldots$, $\alpha_n$ distinct real numbers, $\rho_1$, $\ldots$, $\rho_n$ $ >0$ and $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$.  The function

$$\phi(x) = x - \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\rho_i}{x- \alpha_i} -\beta $$

invariates the Lebesgue measure  on $\mathbb{R}$.

Lemma: For any $a \in \mathbb{R}$ the equation

\begin{eqnarray*}
 x- \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\rho_i}{x- \alpha_i} -\beta = u
\end{eqnarray*}
has $n+1$ distinct real root with sum $u + \sum_i \alpha_i + \beta $. 
Use Viete.

Lemma: Let $I$ an interval in $\mathbb{R}$ of length $l$. Then the preimage $\phi^{-1} (I)$ is a union of $n+1$ disjoint intervals of total length $l$.

Consequence:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} (f\circ \phi)\, d\,\mu = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f\  d\mu$$

Composing two rational maps that invariate the measure gets a third one.  They will have singularities in general.

For $f(x) = e^{-\frac{x^2}{a}}$ the composition  $f (\phi(x))$  is still smooth due to the rapid decay at $\infty$ of $e^{-\frac{x^2}{a}}$.

Comment: That is remarkably simple and straightforward. +1

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate on how you concluded this?

Comment: @user137794: Added more detail.

Comment: @Tom-Tom: Thanks! Added more detail.

Comment: For $f(x) = e^{-\frac{x^2}{a}}$ the function $f(\phi(x))$ is still smooth.

Comment: @orangeskid, If you don't mind, would you recommend some references to this argument? It is quite interesting!

Comment: @sos440: This second lemma I've seen in a textbook of ergodic theory, t

Comment: @sos440: Now I have to recall where... In any case, these form the semigroup of rational maps that invariate the measure ( composition is of the same form)

Comment: @orangeskid, That's a fascinating fact. Thank you!

Comment: @sos440: My pleasure!

Comment: I'm interested in your lemma 2, but I haven't studied so much ergodic theory. Can you either give a more explicit reference or give me some more words to look up to try to find a reference? Thank you.

Comment: @mixedmath This is known as Glasser's Master Theorem (goes back to at least G Boole (1857)). Here is a [PDF](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1983-40-162/S0025-5718-1983-0689471-1/S0025-5718-1983-0689471-1.pdf).

Answer (score 7):

Adding another solution owing to a friend of mine.

Through some algebra, the integral is equivalent to

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left(-\frac1{611}\left((x-x^{-1})-13\right)^2\right)\ dx$$

Then using the following identity

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x-x^{-1})\ dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\ dx$$

We have

$$\begin{align}
&\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left(-\frac1{611}\left((x-x^{-1})-13\right)^2\right)\ dx\\
=&\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left(-\frac1{611}(x-13)^2\right)\ dx\\
=&\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left(-\frac1{611}x^2\right)\ dx\\
=&\sqrt{611\pi}
\end{align}$$

Comment: +1 for the identity $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x-x^{-1})\ dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\ dx$$but how to prove it? CC: @sos440

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova http://math.stackexchange.com/a/457271/137794

Comment: @user137794 Thanks. That proof has completed my answer ≧◠◡◠≦✌

Answer (score 6):

Using identity in @user137794's answer:
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x-x^{-1})\ dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\ dx
\end{equation}
where the complete proof can be seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/457231/133248). The problem can be generalised to evaluate

> \begin{equation}
> \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left(-\frac{(x^2-bx-1)^2}{ax^2}\right)\ dx = \sqrt{a\pi}
> \end{equation}

**Proof:**

It's easy to see that $\dfrac{(x^2-bx-1)^2}{ax^2}=\dfrac{1}{a}\left(x-x^{-1}-b\right)^2$, then
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left(-\frac{(x^2-bx-1)^2}{ax^2}\right)\ dx &=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left(-\frac{(x-x^{-1}-b)^2}{a}\right)\ dx\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left(-\frac{(x-b)^2}{a}\right)\ dx\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left(-\frac{y^2}{a}\right)\ dy\\
&=\sqrt{a}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left(-z^2\right)\ dz\\
&=\sqrt{a\pi}
\end{align}
Therefore
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left(-\frac{(x^2-13x-1)^2}{611x^2}\right)\ dx = \sqrt{611\pi}
\end{equation}

Comment: Nice generalization! It's interesting, that $b$ does not matter, on the other hand $-1$ is how important!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution without using [Glasser's master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glasser%27s_master_theorem), which some of the other answers utilized.

$$I = \int_{-\infty}^\infty\exp\left(-\frac{(x^2-13x-1)^2}{611x^2}\right)\ dx$$

$$ = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left(-\frac{(x-\frac{1}{x}-13)^2}{611}\right)\ dx $$

$$ = \int_{-\infty}^0 \exp\left(-\frac{(x-\frac{1}{x}-13)^2}{611}\right)\ dx  + \int_{0}^{\infty} \exp\left(-\frac{(x-\frac{1}{x}-13)^2}{611}\right)\ dx  $$

$$ \overset{\color{red} x\color{red}\rightarrow \color{red}-\color{red}1\color{red}/\color{red}t }{=} \int_{0}^\infty \exp\left(-\frac{(-\frac{1}{t}+t-13)^2}{611}\right)\ \frac{dt}{t^2}  + \int_{-\infty}^{0} \exp\left(-\frac{(-\frac{1}{t}+t-13)^2}{611}\right)\ \frac{dt}{t^2}  $$

$$ = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left(-\frac{(-\frac{1}{t}+t-13)^2}{611}\right)\ \frac{dt}{t^2} $$

Therefore, $$
2 I = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left(-\frac{(x-\frac{1}{x}-13)^2}{611}\right) (1+\frac{1}{x^2}) dx $$
$$ = \int_{-\infty}^{-1} + \int_{-1}^{0} + \int_{0}^1 + \int_{1}^\infty \left[\exp\left(-\frac{(x-\frac{1}{x}-13)^2}{611}\right) (1+\frac{1}{x^2}) dx\right]$$

$$ \overset{\color{red}( \color{red} x \color{red}-\color{red}1\color{red}/\color{red}x \color{red}) \rightarrow \color{red} z}{=} \int_{-\infty}^{0} \exp\left(-\frac{(z-13)^2}{611}\right) dz + \int_{0}^{\infty} \exp\left(-\frac{(z-13)^2}{611}\right) dz + \int_{-\infty}^{0} \exp\left(-\frac{(z-13)^2}{611}\right) dz + \int_{0}^{\infty} \exp\left(-\frac{(z-13)^2}{611}\right) dz $$

$$ = 2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp\left(-\frac{(z-13)^2}{611}\right) dz $$

$$ = 2 \sqrt{611 \pi}$$

Hence, $$I = \sqrt{611 \pi}.$$

Here, we could replace $611$ with any positive number.