# Math competition problem, prove that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\pi x^2 \left(\frac{\alpha +x}{\beta +x}\right)^2}dx=1~$ for $~0<\beta<\alpha$.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, contest-math, closed-form

Recently there was a math competition in our university where this question

> Question: Prove that $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\pi  x^2 \left(\frac{\scriptstyle\alpha +x}{\scriptstyle\beta +x}\right)^2}dx=1~$ for $~0<\beta<\alpha$

has been asked, but nobody could solve it. I know that
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\pi  x^2}dx=1
$$
but this doesn't help much. What are possible routes to deal with this kind of integrals? Any integration experts has any clue how this is done? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried contour integration? I feel like that might work.

Comment: Just an idea: your starting point might actually be helpful if you do it the "Feynman way": for $\beta = \alpha$ the integrand reduces to your simpler special case. Now take the partial derivative with respect to $\beta$ (hopefully constant).

Comment: what university?

Comment: Glasser's Master theorem might help

Comment: Yes Glasser's theorem does solve this, but it's a bit too heavy machinery to be used on a competition problem imo. Would be interesting to know if this is in the curriculum / supposed to be known for students taking this problem.

Comment: Similar type of question which might be useful: [Is $\int_{\mathbb R} f(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{x-x_k})dx$ independent of $x_k$'s for certain $f$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1257554/147873) The answer seems to provide an answer for this question also.

Comment: @winther i guess that in this case a more elementary solution exists. I can't believe that Glasser is in the standard cirriculum at any university at the planet

Answer (score 10):

One may write
$$
 x \left(\frac{\alpha +x}{\beta +x}\right)=x-\frac{(\alpha-\beta)\beta}{x+\beta}+\alpha-\beta \tag1
$$ then, since $(\alpha-\beta)\beta>0$, one may use the [G. Boole](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GlassersMasterTheorem.html) (1857) result,

> $$
> \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f\left(x-\frac{a}{x-b}\right)\mathrm{d}x=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x)\: \mathrm{d}x,\qquad a>0.  \tag2
> $$

giving, with $(1)$,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\pi  x^2 \left(\frac{\scriptstyle\alpha +x}{\scriptstyle\beta +x}\right)^2}dx&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\pi \left(x-\frac{(\alpha-\beta)\beta}{x+\beta}+\alpha-\beta \right)^2}dx
\\\\&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\pi \left(x+\alpha-\beta \right)^2}dx
\\\\&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\pi x^2}dx
\\\\&=1
\end{align}
$$
as announced.

Comment: It's always you :)

Comment: I can't except this.There must be a more elementary solution.

Comment: @Tyrell I gave the general result, but in our case this is just an elementary change of variable, please see this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457231/how-to-prove-int-infty-infty-fxdx-int-infty-infty-f-left/1461393#1461393