# Supremum of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{p'(x)^2}{p(x)^2+p'(x)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, optimization, definite-integrals

> **Question.** Let $P_d = \{ p \in \mathbb{R}[x] : \deg p = d\}$ denote the set of all degree $d$ polynomials with real coefficients. Also, for $p \in \mathbb{R}[x]$, define
>
> $$ I(p) = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{p'(x)^2}{p(x)^2+p'(x)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x. $$
>
> Is it possible to identify the supremum of $I(\cdot)$ over $P_d$? In other words, what is
>
> $$ C_d := \sup_{p \in P_d} I(p) = \ ? $$

This question is motivated by [this posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1240613/9340). Here are some observations:

1. If $p \in P_d$ has only real zeros, then $I(p) = d$ holds. (See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1261650/9340) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1261388/9340).)
2. $I(p) \leq d^{3/2}$ for any $p \in P_d$. Indeed, write $p(x) = a (x - \alpha_1) \dots (x - \alpha_d)$. Then by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,
   $$ \left| \frac{p'(x)}{p(x)} \right|^2
   = \left| \sum_{k=1}^{d} \frac{1}{x - \alpha_k} \right|^2
   \leq d \sum_{k=1}^{d} \frac{1}{\left| x - \alpha_k \right|^2}. $$
   Now by noting that the map $f(t) = \frac{t}{t+1}$ is increasing and [subadditive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subadditivity#Definitions) for $t \geq 0$,
   \begin{align*}
   I(p)
   &= \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f\biggl( \left| \frac{p'(x)}{p(x)} \right|^2 \biggr) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
   &\leq \sum_{k=1}^{d} \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f\biggl( \frac{d}{\left| x - \alpha_k \right|^2} \biggr) \,\mathrm{d}x \\
   &\leq \sum_{k=1}^{d} \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f\biggl( \frac{d}{(x - \operatorname{Re}(\alpha_k))^2} \biggr) \,\mathrm{d}x \\
   &= d^{3/2}.
   \end{align*}
   In particular, we learn that $d \leq C_d \leq d^{3/2}$.
3. When $d = 2$, we can show that $C_2 = 2$ by using the first part and a direct computation.
4. For $d \geq 4$, we seem to have $C_d > d$. Indeed, numerical experiments reveal that we can find $a, b > 0$ satisfying
   $$I((x^2+a^2)(x - b)^{d-2}) > d.$$
   However, $C_d$ seems much smaller than $d^{3/2}$, differing from $d$ only by a tiny fraction.
5. A simple computation shows that
   $$ I(p) = d - 2 \sum_{\substack{\alpha : \operatorname{Im}(\alpha) < 0 \\ p(\alpha) = ip'(\alpha) }} \operatorname{Re} \biggl( \frac{1}{1+p''(\alpha)/p(\alpha)} \biggr). $$
   This provides an alternative proof of part 1. Indeed, if $p$ has only real zeros, then $\operatorname{Im}\bigl(\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}\bigr)$ and $\operatorname{Im}(z)$ always have the opposite signs, and so, the summation part in the above formula vanishes.

Comment: What is the computation done to obtain the formula in point 5? it looks like a residue theorem but I'm not sure, nothing I can contribute but great question

Comment: @DanielD., Thank you for your attention! It is indeed a consequence of the residue theorem applied to $$\operatorname{Re}\biggl[\oint_{C_R}\frac{p'(z)}{p'(z)-ip(z)} \, \mathrm{d}z\biggr]$$ along the lower semicircular contour $C_R$ as the radius $R$ tends to $\infty$.

Comment: Not very useful but at the supremum we have $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x^{k-1}pp'(xp'-kp)}{(p^2+p'^2)^2}\,dx=0$$ for every $0\le k\le d$.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire, Thank you for the comment. Is your formula a consequence of the variational characterization?

Comment: Yes. It results from letting $p=\sum a_ix^i$ and setting each $I_{a_i}=0$.

Comment: You can look at theorem 3 https://www.researchgate.net/publication/27363999_On_a_polynomial_inequality_of_P_Erdos_and_T_Grunwald . Perhaps there is something interesting .

Answer (score 0):

For point $4)$, what numerical simulation did you use? I tried to simulate that specific polynomial, $p(x)=(x^2+a^2)(x-b)^2$, for $d=4$ and I got[image: Graph for the polynomial]

for $I(p)$. Indeed for $a=0$, $p(x)$ has all real roots so by your point $1)$ the center line in the above graph is exactly $4$. Since it appears that everything is increasing towards this line, it would appear that the maximum of $I(p)$ is $4$ for this case.

---

EDIT:

After getting the points $a=\frac{1}{\sqrt{500}}$ and $b=\frac{1}{10}$ I can recreate the same plot above but zoomed in:

[image: Strange behavior]

The right side of this graph is just ever so slightly greater than $4$. However, this graph just raises more questions than answers in my mind: what is that valley, why is it so steep and sudden, etc.?

Comment: I utilized Mathematica 11. For example, you can check that $$p(x)=(x-\tfrac{1}{10})^2(x^2+\tfrac{1}{500})\qquad\Rightarrow\qquad I(p)=4.0001885717300436549\cdots.$$ I am quite certain that this is not an artifact of numerical computation.

Comment: Thank you, with those numbers I was able to zoom in and see... something? I really have no idea what the graph shows at this point.