# Evaluating $\int_{0}^{\infty} \left[\left(\frac{2015}{2015+x}+\cdots +\frac{2}{2+x}+\frac{1}{1+x}-x\right)^{2016}+1 \right] ^{-1}\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, recreational-mathematics

I need to evaluate $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \left[\left(\frac{2015}{2015+x}+\cdots  +\frac{2}{2+x}+\frac{1}{1+x}-x\right)^{2016}+1 \right] ^{-1}\mathrm{d}x
$$

I've been told that the way forward is showing that the integral is the same as $$\int_0^{\infty} (x^{2016} + 1)^{-1} \, \mathrm{d}x$$

i.e: that the weird sum of fractions doesn't affect the integral.

I've tried $$\sum_{n=1}^{2015} \frac{n}{n+x} = \sum_{n=1}^{2015} \left(1 - \frac{x}{n+x}\right) = 2015 - \sum_{n=1}^{2015} \frac{x}{n+x}$$

but it's getting me nowhere.

Comment: Around $x =1$, $(x^{2016}-1)= (x-1)(1+\cdots)$, so isn't there an issue with the easier integral? So should the - be a +?

Comment: @peterag - typo on my part, corrected now - thanks! :)

Comment: Why do you need to integrate that particular integral - where did it arise? Did you simply make it up?

Comment: @CarlMummert It was given to me by a friend.

Comment: Is this an early Xmas present from your friend ?

Comment: So what you want is $\sum_{n=1}^{2015} \frac{n}{n+x} = 2x$, correct?

Comment: @VarunIyer - I don't think so, the integral is the same, not the integrand.

Comment: @VarunIyer and it cannot be - take $x\to\infty$.

Comment: The two integrals are not equal, the first one is around $1.366$, the second one is around $1$. maybe you want to replace the bound of the first integral from $\int_0^\infty$ to $\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty$ ...

Comment: @achillehui - I'm fairly sure I've written it down correctly, I'll have a check - but perhaps the tail of your estimation is significant?

Comment: the terms in the bracket is will not simplify to x. just keep x=0 and see the first term yields 2015.

Comment: I never said it would simplify to x.

Comment: The reason I suggest replacing the limit of first integral from $\int_0^\infty$ to $\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty$ because the statement will become true. Alternatively, the two integral will be equal if you replace both lower limit from $0$ to $-\infty$.

Comment: These problems usually come from general statements, so I would expect this one to be valid for a large class of natural numbers, not just for $2015$. Nevertheless, (superficially) trying it for $1$ doesn't seem to work.

Comment: $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\left[\left(\frac{2015}{2015+x}+\cdots +\frac{2}{2+x}+\frac{1}{1+x}-x\right)^{2016}+1\right]^{-1}\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\left[\left(2015+x\text{H}_x-x\text{H}_{2015+x}-x\right)^{2016}+1\right]^{-1}\space\text{d}x$$

As far as I got, I got this

Comment: What's with all the downvotes?

Comment: Are you happy with @achillehui's "The reason I suggest..." comment above?  See   the answers to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/950712/how-to-compute-int-infty-infty-exp-left-fracx2-13x-12611x2-rig/950848#950848.  Achille's argument there applies here, as the "Added" section of orangeskid's answer explains.

Comment: @peterag the underlying trick is known as [Glasser's Master Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GlassersMasterTheorem.html). For more details, see the original paper  `Glasser, M. L. "A Remarkable Property of Definite Integrals." Math. Comput. 40, 561-563, 1983.`, an online copy can be found [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1983-40-162/S0025-5718-1983-0689471-1/S0025-5718-1983-0689471-1.pdf).

Comment: @achillehui - thanks for the link... And the ideas are nice.

Answer (score 12):

Edited: This integral evaluation is of a related integral which is equivalent to $\int^{\infty}_0(x^{2016}+1)^{-1}dx$, for the original integral in the question, differs in evaluation for limits from $0$ to $\infty$ owing to symmetry considerations discussed in the comments.

---

$$I=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left[\left(\frac{2015}{2015+x}+\cdots  +\frac{2}{2+x}+\frac{1}{1+x}-x\right)^{2016}+1 \right] ^{-1}\mathrm{d}x
$$
$$I=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left[\left(\sum^{2015}_{i=1}\frac{i}{x+i}-x\right)^{2016}+1 \right] ^{-1}\mathrm{d}x
$$

Now, letting $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^{2016}+1}$, and noting that $f(x)=f(-x)$,
$$I=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f\left(\sum^{2015}_{i=1}\frac{i}{x+i}-x\right)\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f\left(-\left(\sum^{2015}_{i=1}\frac{i}{x+i}-x\right)\right)\mathrm{d}x$$
$$I=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f\left(x-\sum^{2015}_{i=1}\frac{i}{x-(-i)}\right)\mathrm{d}x \tag {1}$$
Using [Glasser's Master Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GlassersMasterTheorem.html), 
$$I=\frac{1}{2}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} f(x)\ \mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{2}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{1}{x^{2016}+1}\ \mathrm{d}x=\int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{1}{x^{2016}+1}\ \mathrm{d}x \tag {2}$$

---

Now we know that $$B(a,b)=\int^{\infty}_0\frac{t^{a-1}}{(1+t)^{a+b}}dt$$
From $(2)$,after substituting $x^{2016} =t$,
$$I=\frac{1}{2016}\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{t^{\frac{1}{2016}-1}}{(1+t)^{\frac{1}{2016}+\frac{2015}{2016}}}dt=\frac{1}{2016}B(\frac{1}{2016},\frac{2015}{2016})$$
Therefore $$\color{red}{I=\frac{1}{2016}\frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2016})\Gamma(\frac{2015}{2016})}{\Gamma(1)}=\frac{\pi}{2016\sin(\frac{\pi}{2016})}\approx1.0000004047320180811575}$$

Comment: Next you can put $x^{2016} =t$ and evaluate in terms of Beta function namely $B(1/2016,2015/2016)/2016=\pi/(2016\sin(\pi/2016))$

Comment: In case you are wondering this downvote is not mine. I do not downvote anonymously.

Comment: I know. 
And thank you! I'll modify the answer. (Rather, add on)

Comment: How did you get the expression with pi? @ParamanandSingh I tried to use the identity given in wiki (for Beta function) but to no avail.

Comment: Never mind - Gamma function property gives the answer. Thank once again! @ParamanandSingh

Comment: Is $I$ symmetric to the origin? I think of course not and you should not expand the integral to negative reals...

Comment: @didgogns Could you elaborate?

Comment: Let $f$ be the function which satisfies $I=\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)\mathrm{d}x$. We can say $2I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\mathrm{d}x$ only when $f$ is even and is symmetric to the origin. However, it seems obvious that $f$ is not an even function.

Comment: Because x belongs to reals,  $\frac{1}{1+x^{2016}} $ is an even function right?

Comment: $x^{2016}$ is even: That's true. But it's not what @didgogns pointed out. So, your second and third line is not quite clear.

Comment: @FelixMarin I mean f(x) is both symmetric to the origin and is even. What are the second/third lines which are not clear? (Don't get what lines you're referring to when you say second and third)

Comment: @FelixMarin WA numerically confirms that $2I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ where $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^8}$, $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^{12}}$, $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^{118}}$ and so on. Computation time exceeds for $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^{2016}}$.

If it's a conceptual error I'm guilty of, please do let me know by elaborating.

Comment: I meant that $\left[\left(\frac{2015}{2015+x}+\cdots  +\frac{2}{2+x}+\frac{1}{1+x}-x\right)^{2016}+1 \right] ^{-1}$ is not likely to be symmetric to the origin and is even, not $(1+x^{2n})^{-1}$

Comment: @didgogns Alright, I see. Hmm.. How would we go about showing its symmetricity to confirm that then?

Comment: It is not symmetrical. If you compute the sum $p(x) =\left( \sum_{k=1}^{2015}\frac{k}{k+x} \right)- x$ at $x = \pm \frac12$, you will notice $p(\frac12) \approx 1003.7, p(-\frac12) \approx 3027.3$ This implies $\frac{1}{p(x)^{2016} + 1}$ takes different value at $x = \pm \frac12$.

Comment: @achillehui Thank you!

So is there a way to show that the integral in question is equivalent to $\int_0^{\infty} (x^{2016} + 1)^{-1} \, \mathrm{d}x$, without facing a symmetricity issue like I did while trying to utilize the G.M.Theorem?

Comment: I don't think they are equivalent. I have computed $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{p(x)^{2016}+1} dx$ numerically, its value is around $1.366$. Even though it is very hard to get an accurate result for this, the difference with the value of $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^{2016}+1}dx \approx 1$ is so big that the two integral should really be different.

Comment: If you have the time, post your numerical evaluation of the integral in question as an answer. And thank you for the clarifications..

Comment: @Kugelblitz I do that one and a half year ago. I already completely forget the details ;-p

Answer (score 12):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\int_{0}^{\infty}\bracks{\pars{{2015 \over 2015 + x} + \cdots +
> {2 \over 2 + x} + {1 \over 1 + x} - x}^{2016} + 1}^{-1}\,\dd x:\ {\large ?}}$.

\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\infty}\bracks{\pars{{2015 \over 2015 + x} + \cdots +
{2 \over 2 + x} + {1 \over 1 + x} - x}^{2016} + 1}^{-1}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd x \over \mc{F}^{2016}\pars{x} + 1}\quad
\mbox{where}\quad\mc{F}\pars{x} \equiv \sum_{k = 1}^{2015}{k \over k + x} - x
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
\mc{F}\pars{x} & \equiv 
\sum_{k = 1}^{2015}{k \over k + x} - x =
2015 - x\sum_{k = 1}^{2015}{1 \over k + x} - x
\\[5mm] & =
2015 - x\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\pars{{1 \over k + x} - {1 \over k + 2015 + x}} - x \\[5mm] & =
2015 - x\pars{H_{x + 2015} - H_{x}} - x\qquad
\pars{~H_{z}:\ Harmonic\ Number~}
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
&\bbx{\mc{F}\pars{x} =
2015 - \pars{\vphantom{\large A}H_{x + 2015} - H_{x} + 1}x}
\\[5mm]
&\mbox{Some characteristic behaviours of}\ \mc{F}\pars{x}\ \mbox{are}\
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\ds{\mc{F}\pars{0} = 2015}
\\[2mm]
\ds{\mc{F}\pars{x} \to -\infty\quad \mbox{as}\quad x \to \infty}
\\[2mm]
\ds{\mc{F}'\pars{x} \leq 0\,,\quad \forall\ x \geq 0}
\\[2mm]
\ds{\mc{F}\pars{r} = 0\,,\quad r \approx 939.105}
\\[2mm]
\ds{\mc{F}\pars{939.105} \approx -6.28337 \times 10^{-4}}
\\[2mm]
\ds{\mc{F}'\pars{939.105} \approx -1.46404}
\end{array}\right.
\\[1cm]
&\mbox{Hereafter, I'll perform a numerical evaluation which is based in the Laplace Method}:
\\
&\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd x \over \mc{F}^{2016}\pars{x} + 1} =
\int_{0}^{r}{\dd x \over \mc{F}^{2016}\pars{r - x} + 1} +
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd x \over \mc{F}^{2016}\pars{x + r} + 1}
\\[5mm] \approx &\
2\int_{0}^{\infty}
\expo{-\bracks{\mc{F}'\pars{r}}^{\large 2016}x^{\large 2016}}\,\dd x =
{2 \over \verts{\mc{F}'\pars{r}}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-x^{\large 2016}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
{2 \over \verts{\mc{F}'\pars{r}}}\,{1 \over 2016}
\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{1/2016 - 1}\expo{-x}\,\dd x =
{1 \over 1008}\,{1 \over \verts{\mc{F}'\pars{r}}}\,\Gamma\pars{1 \over 2016}
\\[5mm] & \approx \bbx{1.36569}
\quad\mbox{with}\quad
\left.\mc{F}'\pars{r}\right\vert_{\ r\ \approx\ 939.105} \approx -1.46404
\end{align}

> This value $\ds{\pars{~1.36569~}}$ is the numerical one reported by [$\texttt{@achille hui}$ in another answer comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2268083/85343).

Comment: +1 cool, I never thought of actually approximate the integral analytically.

Comment: @achillehui Thanks.

Comment: +1 Thanks for a much more accurate and satisfying computation. :)
Gave you the bounty.

Comment: @Kugelblitz Thanks a lot. $\left(\,\substack{\bullet\quad\bullet\\
\mid\\[2mm]
\smile\\[0.5mm]\smile}\,\right)$