# Integrating the Lambert-W function

Tags: integration, special-functions, lambert-w

I was attempting to integrate the [Lambert-W Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) and my answer differs from that given by Wikipedia and Wolfram Alpha so I figure I must be doing something wrong.

We have $f^{-1} = W(z)$, $f=ze^z$, and $F = e^z(z-1)$. Using the formula in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/942476/274085):

\begin{align*}
\int W(z) \,dz &= zW(z) - \left[ \left( e^z(z-1) \right) \circ W(z) \right](z) + c \\
&= zW(z) - e^{W(z)} (W(z)-1) + c
\end{align*}

However, the W|A and Wikipedia give:

> $$ \int W(z) \,dz = z\left( W(z) + \frac{1}{W(z)} - 1 \right) + c $$

Wikipedia gives the identity $\int_0^e W(z) \,dz = e-1$, which my antiderivative gives as a solution as well. So I figure the two primitives must just differ by a constant $c_0$? What is the difference between my solution and the other? or how do I show that they are the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's easy: due to the definition of $W,$ we have $W(z)\,e^{W(z)}=z$, meaning $e^{W(z)}=\frac{z}{W(z)}.$ Substituting this in the fist expression for the antiderivative, we get the second one.

Comment: well now I feel silly, thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't want you to feel silly!

Answer (score 2):

Integrating inverse functions can often be simplified using integration by parts:
$$
\begin{align}
\int W(z)\,\mathrm{d}z
&=\int x\,\mathrm{d}\!\left(xe^x\right)\\
&=x^2e^x-\int xe^x\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=x^2e^x-xe^x+\int e^x\,\mathrm{d}x\\[3pt]
&=x^2e^x-xe^x+e^x+C\\[6pt]
&=\left(W(z)^2-W(z)+1\right)\frac{z}{W(z)}+C\\
&=z\left(W(z)-1+\frac1{W(z)}\right)+C
\end{align}
$$