# The integral : $\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty x^n \operatorname{sech}(x)\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

How can I evaluate

$$\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty x^n \operatorname{sech}(x)\mathrm dx?$$

I was trying integration by parts but it seemed like it is getting more complicated.
$$\int_0^\infty x^n \operatorname{sech}(x)\mathrm dx=\left.2x^n\arctan\left(\tanh(x/2)\right)\right|_0^\infty-2n\int_0^\infty x^{n-1}\arctan(\tanh(x/2))\mathrm dx$$
Herein, it seems like we have to apply integration by parts $n$ times but it is not practically possible.

> This question is a more general problem of the integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{e^x+e^{-x}}\mathrm dx$, which I was first solving.
> Let me know if there's any other method for evaluating this integral. It will be highly appreciated.

I have posted my solution employing a method using Geometric series to which [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function) helped me in finding the solution.
Please see my answer below.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with this post? I can see a close vote here. Perhaps 'answer your own question' is controversial in practice as opposed to what was mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/?_ga=2.28848700.1250830019.1618675110-2119719802.1618675110).

Comment: Answering your question is fine. But I don't see the link between your question and your answer. Your answer should have proceeded with the approach given in question.

Comment: Or perhaps you should indicate some alternative approach in the question which had some issue and you later resolved the issue and posted that as an answer.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh One user commented - 'Still the question should have a context' - that's why I added this. This question cannot be solved by integration by parts or if it can, it is going to be extremely tough.

Comment: Yes context is important and it need not necessarily consist of an attempt. You should include details like the source of problem too. You have given one approach which you think has hit a dead end. Then you may try to describe your thought process which led to the final solution.

Comment: Currently your answer seems to appear from out of the blue.

Comment: Also adding context just for the sake of formality is not really the spirit here. If someone asks you for a context you need to honestly describe how you stumbled on the problem and what are your own ideas for a solution and perhaps you need to write in such a way that it motivates other users to think about the problem.

Comment: I generated this problem on my own while solving another integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{e^x-e^{-x}}$ with the help of [This article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124653/discussion-between-nikhil-kumar-singh-and-paramanand-singh).

Comment: I have edited the question adding the context yet the downvote! Could I know the reason?

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but I will try to discuss your question CURED chatroom.

Comment: Perhaps I shouldn't ask this. One more close vote! If the context is bothering people, I have already added the context after discussion with @ParamanandSingh.

Comment: Please also raise your concern in [constructive feedback](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43593/constructive-feedback).

Comment: @NikhilKumarSingh I don't know if this has already been covered, but when you do formulate a self answered post, draw attention to the fact you are self-answering in the problem statement. Otherwise casual readers may not notice that it is happening.

Comment: @rschwieb I have mentioned - 'I have posted my solution employing ...'

Comment: @NikhilKumarSingh Yes it's there, but a little bit hidden in the paragraph further nested in a block. I mean that it'd be more obvious if the post just ended with "please see my attempted solution below."

Comment: @rschwieb Added!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty \frac{x^n}{\cosh x}dx \overset{t=e^{-x}}=&\int_0^1 \frac{(-1)^n\ln^n t}{1+t^2}dt=n!\>\text{Im}\>\text{Li}_{n+1}(i)
\end{align}

Answer (score 14):

\begin{align}\mathcal{I}&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty \frac{x^n}{\cosh(x)}\mathrm dx\\&=\int_0^\infty \frac{x^n}{e^x+e^{-x}}\mathrm dx\\&=\int_0^\infty \frac{x^ne^{-x}}{1+e^{-2x}}\mathrm dx.\end{align}

---

Proposition: $$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{s-1}e^{-x}}{1+e^{-2x}}\mathrm dx=\beta(s)\Gamma(s),$$ where $\beta(s)$ is the Dirichlet beta function defined as $\beta(s)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^s}$.

*Proof*:\begin{align}\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}\left(\frac{e^{-x}}{1-(-e^{-2x})}\right)\mathrm dx&=\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^ke^{-(2k+1)x}\right)\mathrm dx \text{, using geometric series}\\&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\int_0^\infty x^{s-1} e^{-(2k+1)x}\mathrm dx\\&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^s}\displaystyle\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}e^{-x}\mathrm dx\text{, substituting $(2k+1)x\mapsto x$}\\&=\beta(s)\Gamma(s). \end{align}

---

Therefore,
$$\mathcal{I}=\beta(n+1)\Gamma(n+1).$$

We can evaluate for different values of $n\ge 0$.
For $n=1$, $\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty x\operatorname{sech}(x)=\beta(2)\Gamma(2)=G$, where $G$ is Catalan's constant.
For $n=2$, $\int_0^\infty x^2\operatorname{sech}(x)=2\beta(3)\Gamma(3)=\frac{\pi^3}{8}$

Comment: Why did you post your attempt as an answer rather in the main body of the OP?

Comment: @MartinØdegaard Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/?_ga=2.86980888.1250830019.1618675110-2119719802.1618675110).

Comment: Do you just want to verify your solution?

Comment: @VIVID I verified this by Wolfram Alpha. I posted this as 'answer your own question'.

Comment: Still the question *itself* should have a context, not be just a problem statement only.

Comment: @metamorphy I added context to the question.

Comment: For the one who believes that I have posted my attempt as answer then you are wrong. This is not attempt - This is an answer.

Comment: @meta, in my opinion, a self-answer obviates the need for context.

Comment: Another opinion completely opposite to Gerry's one [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15017/can-i-post-a-question-and-an-answer-just-because-i-think-it-helps-others/15020#15020)

Comment: @Arctic, I don't see it. That link addresses the question of usefulness, my remark addresses the question of context. Not the same thing.

Comment: @ArcticChar I've never seen anyone dispute in meta that self-answers should not count toward context.  That a self-answer is context-in-a-different-location is sort of a no-brainer.

Comment: Gerry's comment implies that no other context is needed for a self-answered question. This is different from what you said (which I agree). Whether this is sufficient was frequently discussed in meta (e.g. [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28241/is-self-answer-considered-as-adding-sufficient-context)) and the answer suggests that in general it is not sufficient.  @rschwieb

Answer (score 0):

Letting $\tan \theta=e^{-x}$ transforms the integral into

$$
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{e^x+e^{-x}}dx=(-1)^n \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln^n (\tan \theta) d \theta
$$

By my [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4501957/732917),
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln ^{n}(\tan \theta) d \theta =(-1)^{n} \beta(n+1) \Gamma(n+1)$$
Hence$$\boxed{\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{e^x+e^{-x}}= \beta(n+1) \Gamma(n+1)}$$